# Copy email subject in outlook to excel using vba with two email address?

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have two email address. The first is `address1@domain.com.vn` and the second is `address2@domain.com.vn`.

I want to copy email subject in microsoft outlook with second address `address2@domain.com.vn` to excel using vba. I use bellow code but it do not work.

```
Sub GetFromInbox()
Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim Pst_Folder_Name
Dim MailboxName
'Dim date1 As Date
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("sheet1").Visible = True
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
MailboxName = "address2@domain.com.vn"
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
Set Fldr = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)
i = 2
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
'For Each olMail In olapp.CurrentFolder.Items
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.Subject
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = olMail.SenderName
i = i + 1

Next olMail
End Sub
```

Comment: Removed your actual emails from question - you're not trying to copy your email in your above code

Comment: It's my mistake. Thanks @dbmitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub GetFromInbox()
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Pst_Folder_Name As String, MailboxName As String
    Dim i As Long

    MailboxName = "address2@domain.com.vn"
    Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
        i = 2
        For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
            'For Each olMail In olapp.CurrentFolder.Items
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.Subject
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = olMail.SenderName
            i = i + 1
        Next olMail
    End With

    olapp.Quit
    Set olapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks because of your support. But your code 've not run. The error's in line   `Set Fldr = olapp.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)`

Comment: there's no such line in my code. Please run it exactly as I wrote and let me know

Comment: what didn't run? did you meet any error? if so, what kind of error and thrown by which line?

Comment: A message box: "The attemted operation failed. An object could not be found" and the error in line `Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)` (luunt1@vpb.com.vn is my email address)

Comment: then either folder "luunt1@vpb.com.vn" or its subfolder "Inbox" hasn't been found in your Outlook. If you look at your Ourlook do yo find "luunt1@vpb.com.vn" at the top of the folders list at the left? And does it have a Subfolder "Inbox"?

Comment: Oh. I found it. I were wrong between "vpb" and "vbp" You were excellent. Sorry because I were bothered you

Comment: Don't worry. BTW since my answer was correct and the first one you received, you may want to accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your using [ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211818%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) then you don't need to set your email Inbox, code should run on currently displayed folder in explorer.

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim CurrentExplorer As Explorer
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim App As Outlook.Application
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim xlStarted As Boolean
    Dim Book As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Set App = Outlook.Application
    Set Folder = App.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set Items = Folder.Items

    Set Book = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Sht = Book.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = Sht.Range("A" & Sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    i = LastRow + 1

    For Each Item In Items

        If Item.Class = olMail Then

            Sht.Cells(i, 1) = Item.ReceivedTime
            Sht.Cells(i, 2) = Item.SenderName
            Sht.Cells(i, 3) = Item.Subject

            i = i + 1

            Book.Save

        End If

    Next

    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing

End Sub
```