# Is it possible to create an Excel Macro to open outlook and search through text attachments and open specific named file?

Tags: excel, outlook

I have an email (Outlook 2013) that comes in daily with several text file attachments. The email originates from the same sender "abc@abc.com" and the file attachments have the same name in every daily email "file.txt", "file1.txt", "file2.txt" etc.  The email is delivered into a group inbox subfolder (group\subfolder).  Is it possible to open the email from the subfolder from sender abc@abc.com and open a specific attachment "file2.txt" in Excel (Excel 2013). I'd like to run tests on the text file.  More specifically if line 6 of the text file has ***** in it, then MsgBox "Nothing new"

I'm new to VBA cross-programs and need help.  I've looked all over the web to find a usable example to no avail

If "file2.txt" has ***** on line 6 then an Excel MsgBox will pop up "Nothing New"

Comment: Could you show the VBA code you have tried?

Comment: I don't know how to have Excel look into Outlook then open a file. I only know how to work inside Excel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476442/4539709